# How to update fields of custom user model using Django serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, drf-queryset

I am trying to update the various fields of a user model when the user wants to update it which was created earlier. I am having a custom user model and I am using django rest framework for the update api.

**views.py**

```
class UserUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    """
    Update user.
    """
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserUpdateSerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.user_id = request.data.get("user_id")
        instance.save()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    USER_CHOICES = (
        (1, u'ADMIN'),
        (2, u'SALES'),
        (3, u'KITCHEN'),
        (4, u'EMPLOYEE'),
    )
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='employees/', null = True, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key = True, blank = False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user_group = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=4, choices=USER_CHOICES)
    firebase_token = models.CharField(max_length=150, default=None, null = True)
    shop =  models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=False, default=0)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shop = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('image', 'url', 'phone', 'name', 'user_id','email', 'password', 'is_active', 'user_group', 'shop')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        shop = validated_data.pop('shop')
        user_id = validated_data.pop("user_id")
        print(user_id)
        shopId = Shop.objects.filter(name=shop).values('shop_id').first()
        if shopId is not None:
            shop_id = shopId['shop_id']
            try:
                if user_id is not None:
                    instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
                    instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
                    instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
                    instance.phone = validated_data.get('phone', instance.phone)
                    instance.password = validated_data.get('password', instance.password)
                    instance.user_group = validated_data.get('user_group', instance.user_group)
                    instance.shop_id = validated_data.get('shop_id', instance.shop_id)
                    instance.is_active =  True
                    instance.save()
                    return instance
                else:
                    print("Test")
            except Exception as e:
                return e
        else:
            return None
```

> This is throwing an error saying that the user already exists!

Please assist!

Comment: I’m not an expert but it seems strange to me that you are trying to update the primary key “user_id” in the update method of the view. I’m guessing it doesn’t like you trying to save that change or something. Could be wrong though. Hope it helps.

Comment: @clintsmith I am sorry for that, I deleted the same and still, the same issue exists.

Answer (score 2):

Just Change your serializer like below

```
class UserUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shop = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('image', 'url', 'phone', 'name', 'user_id','email', 'password', 'is_active', 'user_group', 'shop')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        shop = validated_data.pop('shop')
        shop_obj = Shop.objects.filter(name=shop).first()
        if shop_obj:
            instance.shop = shop_obj
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: When I am using POST Method, it is throwing an error saying 
Method Not Allowed: /userupdate/

Comment: @RajuIn you should use `PUT` method for update. To create you shoud use `POST` method

Comment: Bro, I am getting this error..
AssertionError: Expected view UserUpdate to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

Comment: you should pass the pk in url while sending the PUT request like `/userupdate/10/` where 10 is user pk

Comment: This is what happens when I do the same,
/userupdate/tt12345/
AssertionError: Expected view UserUpdate to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
I have added path('userupdate/<str:user_id>/', UserUpdate.as_view())
 in urls.py

Comment: @RajuIn it's not a string. You should pass an integer id. `a = User.objects.get(id=10); print(a.pk)`

Comment: actually in my model the user_id is a string

Comment: share your `User` model

Comment: I have already shared it with the question, Please have a look

Comment: You don't need to explicitly create user id. Django automatically generates a `id` field. You can refer https://learnbatta.com/blog/using-custom-user-model-in-django-23/  to know how to use django models

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling `UserUpdate` API, it will create every new `User` for every new `user_id`. 
I don't know why you are updating `user_id`. Any new `user_id` will create a new `User` instance.
If you want to update other than `user_id`, you need to remove the following line.

1. Remove these lines from `UserUpdate` API View.

   ```
   instance.user_id = request.data.get("user_id")       
   instance.save()
   ```
2. Remove this line from `UserUpdateSerializer`

   ```
   instance.user_id = validated_data.get('user_id', instance.user_id)
   ```
3. Add `lookup_field = 'user_id'` to `UserUpdate` API view
4. Add `user_id` at url, like

   ```
   path('userupdate/<str:user_id>/', UserUpdate.as_view())
   ```

Comment: My user_id is string type and I changed it to <str:user_id>. I have not used the same before and I am trying to test it using these URLs.
MY_IP/userupdate/id/tt12345/
MY_IP/userupdate/tt12345/
Both of these are showing Url Not Found.

Comment: updated answer. MY_IP/userupdate/{user_id}/ should work.

Comment: I am sorry, still it is not working.
Page not found at /userupdate/{tt12345}/

Comment: I have witten {user_id}  to identify it as placeholder rather than string. So, remove {}, try,  /userupdate/tt12345/

Comment: Actually I tried both. Still, it is throwing the same error only...

Comment: Probably, the error is not here. Would you please share your url patterns from root?

Comment: path(r'^userupdate/<str:user_id>/', views.UserUpdate.as_view())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205243/discussion-between-hasan-and-raju-in).